# How to find the closest turtle(s)?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

NetLogo command `distance <agent>` can be used to find the distance of a turtle from another turtle.
However, I am looking for each turtle to be able to find the turtle(s) with the smallest sum of [distance from it + price(a turtle variable)]. How can I get the turtles to do that?

Comment: look at the dictionary for `min-one-of`. If you can't get it to work, come back with your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JenB 's comment helped me solve it.
`set matchedseller min-one-of sellers [distance myself + price ]`